# Concatenating and wrapping on blank space

Tags: sas

I am concatenating three rows of dates and the result looks like this 01/02/2014 02/03/2014 03/04/2014
Now after  I want to stack them in one cell, 
so they are stacked one below the other in one cell;

- date 1
- date 2
- date 3

I greatly appreciate  any help you may offer.
Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by 'stack in one cell'?  SAS doesn't have this concept.  Are you trying to output to excel and want it to appear that way in excel?

Comment: This is what I want:
Jul 31, 2014
Aug 31, 2014
Aug 13, 2014
Jun 23, 2069
.
Jun 21, 2069

Comment: That isn't clear (perhaps because it's in a comment).  Please edit the question to clarify exactly what you want to happen, using SAS-appropriate terminology or explaining yourself in more detail.

Comment: Comments are not an appropriate place to ask a question.  Either edit it into your current question or ask a new one (Depending on how different it is).

Answer (score 0):

If you want three dates stacked one below the other, don't "concatenate" the dates in the three columns in the first place (that would mean turning three values in three columns into one long variable in one column). Use a proc transpose to convert three dates in three columns into three rows, one below the other.

The clearest tutorial I've seen on doing this is at: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/wtol_transpose.htm